# Flutter: When I am trying to run my flutter app using emulator this error occurred. How to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install C:\Users\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk: cmd: Can't find service: package
Error launching application on Android SDK built for x86

Comment: Hard to say. Exact versions involved? Are you sure everything is correctly installed?

Comment: yes, and I fixed the issue. thank you.